# Output information about currently focused component

Tags: java, swing, focus, components

I have lots of JFrames with several components. They're generally built dynamically with all components added dynamically as well, but some are built manually.

Want I want: 
I want to add a new component, say a read-only JTextField, which prints information about the currently focused component in the JFrame. The purpose is to have a really easy way to see where each component fetches its data from (they're generally bound to fields from a database or to some method just returning the data they need) and other interesting stuff. 
Let's just call this the "DebugInfoComponent".

My current idea, which I feel is somewhat primitive: 
I could "just" add a FocusListener to every component of every JFrame, which then notifies the DebugInfoComponent, which then calls setText with the relevant information based on the component being focused.

My question: 
Is there a better way?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Take a look at [`KeyboardFocusManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just made a quick test, and it seems to be exactly what I was looking for - thank you! The key is to add a property listener on focusOwner and that seems to be it :-)
(post as an answer and I'll accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`KeyboardFocusManger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html), you can use it's property change support to monitor changes to the focus state of the application.

You probably want to monitor the `focusOwner` property, but you should investigate the other properties as well